# How should I pass data between middlewares and controllers?

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'd like some opinions on best practices for passing data to/from controllers and middleware - keeping in mind that middleware can be 'before' or 'after'.

In the past, I've made changes to the request and merged inputs.  However, this time I need a solution for the 'after' middleware.  So I'd just rather not depend on the request after the controller has run.

My specific scenario - is that my controller returns a normal view response and my middleware crunches it into a pdf.  So I need to load the paper config in the controller as well as the after middleware.  The paper config changes from template to template.

I'd like to load the paper config in the controller and then ... 'return' that to the middleware tucked inside the response somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace FuquIo\LaravelPdfMaker;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Closure;

class Middleware{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){

        /**
        * This is the only way I have found to change
        * inputs without breaking request validation.
        */
        $inputs = $request->request->all();
        $inputs['data_for_controller'] = 'foo bar';
        $request->replace($inputs);

        // run controller
        $response = $next($request);

        //...do something based on x-controller-info...
        $headers = collect($response->headers->all())->only(['x-data-from-controller']);
        //...

        return $response;
    }
}
```

TheController.php

```
public function theAction(MyValidRequest $request){
    $from_middleware = $request->data_for_controller;
    return response()         
        ->view('myBladeView', ['display_data' => $from_middleware])
        ->header('x-data-from-controller', 'insecure string for middleware');

}
```

**x-headers will be revealed**
There aren't too many situations where this x-header stuff should get used.  It's gonna go to the browser so it's totally not secure.  In my actual use-case the middleware is making pdfs, so the x-headers will say things like 'letter' and 'landscape'.  Totally fine to send that out, perhaps even appropriate to send out.